# What created the /tmp/ICE-unix directory on my EC2 (EBS) instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) EC2 instance has a /tmp/ICE-unix directory, which did not exist there before.

And after doing some research I found it is usually created by ["applications using the Inter-Client Exchange protocol (ICE)"](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.2/doc/RELNOTES5.html). But to my knowledge, I do not have anything using that protocol running on the instance.

What could be the reason this directory has been created?
Maybe an internal AWS component?

Further info:
Security groups for this instance only link to other internal security groups. And some company office IPs. The rest of the world is shut out. And no other colleague has touched this instance.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is a PaaS , check the apps that you subscribe to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @mootmoot I know. But there is nothing in the app that could be creating this directory.

Comment: I will suggest taking snapshot of the EC2 instance, create volume out of it, then attach to another plain Ec2 instance to investigate.

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks for the suggestion